# table of content in a manner what we see as "history of a Safari Browser "

Tags: ios

I need to create a table of content in a manner what we see as "history of a Safari Browser " in which the images can be scrolled to give a vertical wall like effect .. I need the exact effect what we see as in "history of a Safari Browser "...

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're talking about a UITableview.  I can't count how many tutorials, examples, and snippets there are on this site and how many times this question has been asked.  Read the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) first, google your problem, then ask a question if you are unsuccessful.

EDIT, so long as you need a Cover Flow effect, the most famous control is [iCarousel](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/icarousel).

PS, welcome to SO.

Comment: I need a thing very much similar to "Cover Flow Effect" used in MAC...